# How to use putIntExtra for int variable? Error for type of var

Tags: java, android, android-intent

First

```
public class NomenclatureClass {

    private int mImageResourse;

    public NomenclatureClass(int ImageResourse) {
        mImageResourse = ImageResourse;
    }

    public int getImageResourse() {
        return mImageResourse;
    }
}
```

Second

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                NomenclatureClass word = nomenclatureList.get(position);
                int singleImg = word.getImageResourse();
                Intent intent = new Intent(NomenclatureListMK.this, NomenclatureSingleItem.class);
                intent.putExtra("SINGLE_IMG_KEY",singleImg);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Third

```
public class NomenclatureSingleItem extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nomenclature_single_item);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int singleImg = intent.getIntExtra("SINGLE_IMG_KEY");
        ImageView nomenclatureSingleImg = findViewById(R.id.img);
        nomenclatureSingleImg.setImageResource(singleImg);
    }
```

Why I have error "getIntExtra (String, int) in Intent cannot be applied to
(String)" at the line in the Third?

```
int singleImg = intent.getIntExtra("SINGLE_IMG_KEY");
```

What I must to do? Other **string**-variables is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change from:

```
intent.getIntExtra("SINGLE_IMG_KEY");
```

to:

```
intent.getIntExtra("SINGLE_IMG_KEY", 0);
```

when you have to get `int` from `Intent` then you must have to pass default value

Comment: show your error log

Comment: let's not spoonfeed. If he has a new problem, he should ask a new question